# Display values of all Parameters dynamically in textbox

Tags: reporting-services

We have a number of historic SSRS reports and would like to add an optional Glossary as the last page of output showing the values of all the parameters (including multiselects).

Is there any generic way of doing this in code or an assembly, or do I have to hand-crank Expressions that are specific to each report?  e.g. I know that this kind of Expression will work, but will be laborious if i have to do it per report:

```
="Param1:"+CStr(Parameters!p1.Value) + vbCrLF 
+ "Param2:" +CStr(Parameters!p2.Value) + vbCrLF
+ "Param3:" +CStr(Parameters!p3.Value)
```

Thanks,
MrHH

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing the parameter to a custom function. I built a simple sample with a list of countries as the parameter.

Add the following function to the report's code section.

```
Public Function ListSelectedParaValues(ByVal p as Parameter)  as String
    Dim pList as String 
    Dim i as Integer
    If p.IsMultiValue then
        For i  = 0 to p.Count-1
            pList  = pList  + "Value " + cstr(i) + ": " + CStr(p.Value(i)) + " " + chr(13) + chr(10)
        Next
    Else
        pList = CStr(p.Value) 
    End If
    Return pList
End Function
```

To test this, add a textbox and set it's expression to

```
=Code.ListSelectedParaValues(Parameters!Countries)
```

Obviously you need to swap out `Countries` with thename of your parameter, but do NOT append `.Value` as you normally would, it will fail if you do, you just need the parameter name.

The output looks list this

[image]

Comment: That's excellent, thanks. So is there a Parameters collection in a report that allows you to loop over each parameter and then parse each one using your method?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the SSRS documentation explicitly states that you cannot iterate thru the parameters collection and the parameter name must be known.